# Why is "puisque" used in this sentence?

Tags: sens, conjonctions

"**Puisque** je te dis que tu vas finir par te blesser !"

This person said this sentence out of the blue after seeing her daughter suddently dart off. "Because" doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

"Puisque" has the meaning "this is why [I said such and such a thing]" here. This is a usage that is sometimes found. As per the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/puisque):

> [Justifie non pas ce qui est dit, mais, au moyen d'une raison donnée pour déjà connue ou irréfutable, le fait de le dire; porte sur l'énonciation et non sur l'énoncé] … [Justifie un ordre ou un conseil qu'on donne, une proposition qu'on fait]

Answer (score 1):

The TLFi provides this [explanation](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/puisque);

> B. [Justifie non pas ce qui est dit, mais, au moyen d'une raison donnée pour déjà connue ou irréfutable, le fait de le dire; porte sur l'énonciation et non sur l'énoncé]
>
> c [Justifie un ordre ou un conseil qu'on donne, une proposition qu'on fait]
>
> [Dans des formules exclamatives avec ellipse de la principale] (Mais) puisque je vous dis que.
> Il insistait avec maladresse pour qu'elle reprît du gigot: « Mais puisque je vous dis que je n'ai plus faim! ».
> Mais, puisque je vous dis que non, enfin, n'insistez pas!

It is important to realise that there is an ellipse of the main clause in this construction.

"Puisque" has the meaning "do not go (or how can you go)  on along that line of thinking (or along that line of action ) as what you are saying (thinking or doing) contradicts what has been recognised; this truth previously recognised is being reminded to the person the locutor is addressing in what follows "puisque";

- — Donne moi l'adresse du restaurant, je veux y aller …
  — Puisque je t'ai dit qu'il n'y a plus de restaurant à cette adresse !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127844/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-why-is-puisque-used-in-this-sentence).